# Implementing Swift 5.1 collection diffing in internal type

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an iOS app that displays ranged iBeacons in a TableViewController.

To improve performances and test the new Swift 5.1 diffing feature I wrote the following code:

```swift
private func updateBeacons(_ rangedBeacons: [CLBeacon]) {
    guard beacons != rangedBeacons else { return }

    let difference = rangedBeacons.difference(from: beacons)
    // Also tried:
    // let difference = rangedBeacons.difference(from: beacons, by: { $0.uuid == $1.uuid })

    // ...
}
```

When this code is reached a `fatalError` is thrown:

> Fatal error: unsupported: file
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1100.2.259.70/swift/stdlib/public/core/ArrayBuffer.swift,
>   line 231

How can I perform collection diffing on `CLBeacon`s?

The referenced code can be found here:
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ArrayBuffer.swift#L226-L232

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was hitting this issue as well, but in my case I was getting one of the arrays from a Core Data NSFetchedResultsController. I suspect it's related to the fact that the original array comes from Objective-C.

I was able to fix this by wrapping the arrays in a new Array:

```swift
private func updateBeacons(_ rangedBeacons: [CLBeacon]) {
    guard beacons != rangedBeacons else { return }

    let difference = Array(rangedBeacons).difference(from: Array(beacons))

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot  I would probably never have found without this 

Comment: Awesome! Would've gone mad if not for you :)